# Could not find file '/autoload.php

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

I am trying to install phpdocx
I am trying to install it via composer
I have executed this command

```
php composer.json install
```

Then I have typed this url :

```
http://localhost/PHPWord/samples/Sample_01_SimpleText.php
```

But I am getting this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not find file '/autoload.php'. It is generated by Composer. Use 'install --prefer-source' or 'update --prefer-source' Composer commands to move forward.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPWord\bootstrap.php:22 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPWord\samples\Sample_Header.php(2): require_once() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPWord\samples\Sample_01_SimpleText.php(2): include_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPWord\bootstrap.php on line 22
```

How can I solve this error ? Please help me ? I am new in PHP. So please tell how to remove this error ?

Comment: It seems that the error message tells you exactly what to do: `Use 'install --prefer-source' or 'update --prefer-source' Composer commands to move forward.'`... You could also try [following the steps in the documentation](https://github.com/loicfavory/phpdocx).

Comment: I have tried install -- prefer . But 'install' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. is got by me .

Comment: `php composer.json install --prefer-source`

Comment: I have run this command . php composer.json install --prefer-source . But still got the same error .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not install composer . That is why , I am getting this error . To install composer I have downloaded composer.exe . Then I have run it . After that , I have run the following command in command prompt .

```
 php C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar install
```

Then I have run this command :

```
php composer.json install
```

Then The problem is solved .